# Constant $c$ such that a certain function goes to $0$.

Tags: asymptotics

I am studying the function
$${\sqrt x(\ln x)^{(-(\ln x)^{1/k})^5}\over xe^{-(\ln x)^{6/k}}}.$$
According to Desmos, this seems to go to $0$ for $k\ge 3$, but not for $k\le 2$. I was wondering if there was a simple explanation why, but I've found it a bit difficult to manipulate all of these exponentials and logarithms.

Instead of using $1/k$, is there a more precise threshold $c$ such that replacing $1/k$ in the above by $c$ makes this whole thing go to $0$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My first thoughts are (1) Why are you studying this function? Does it come from somewhere in particular? (2) Goes to zero where? As $x$ approaches infinity? (3) There seem to be a number of simplifications you can apply, is there any reason you haven't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=e^t$ which makes the expression to be now
$$\large e^{t^{6/k}-\frac{t}{2}} \,\,t^{-t^{5/k}}$$ which is easier to explore for large values.

In order the expression goes to $0$, it must goes through a maximum first. Computing the first derivative, we need to solve
$$-12 t^{6/k}+k \left(2 t^{5/k}+\color{red}{t}\right)+10 t^{5/k} \log (t)=0 \tag 1$$

Using
$$0 < \color{red}{t} <t^{5/k}$$

the solution of $(1)$ are given in terms of Lambert function
$$t_{(1)}^{1/k}=-\frac{5}{6} k\,\,W\left(-\frac{6}{5  e^{1/5}\, k}\right)$$
$$t_{(2)}^{1/k}=-\frac{5}{6} k\,\,W\left(-\frac{6}{5  e^{3/10}\, k}\right)$$
In the real domain, the argument of Lambert function must be larger than $\frac 1e$.

So
$$t_{(1)}^{1/k}\quad \implies \qquad k > \frac{6 }{5}e^{4/5}=2.67065$$
$$t_{(2)}^{1/k}\quad \implies \qquad k > \frac{6 }{5}e^{7/10}=2.41650$$

I suppose that this explains that.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I'm looking for! For my applications $k$ will be 6, so I'm in good shape, but I was just wondering why the threshold seemed to be in a weird place.